# Why my Serverless Lambda unable to access S3 bucket and items?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I'm sure I've set up my Lambda to have read/write access to the private bucket; more specifically, my lambda will execute `s3.headObject` and `s3.upload`. What am I missing to get this to work?

My Lambda's policy:

```
{
"Statement": [
    {
        "Resource": "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:*:*",
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogGroup",
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    },
    {
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::PRIVATE_BUCKET/folder_name/*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetObject",
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow"
    }
],
"Version": "2012-10-17"
```

}

My S3 buckets policy:

```
 {
    "AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",
    "Description" : "Bucket that is read-accessible internally",
    "Parameters" : {
        "Environment" : {
            "Description" : "dev",
            "Type" : "String",
            "Default" : "dev",
            "AllowedValues" : [ "dev" ]
        }
    },
    "Resources" : {
        "PrivateBucket" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::S3::Bucket",
            "DeletionPolicy" : "Retain",                
        },
        "PrivateBucketPolicy" : {
            "Type" : "AWS::S3::BucketPolicy",
            "Properties" : {
                "PolicyDocument" : {
                    "Id" : "Make anonymous read-only access available on certain networks",
                    "Statement" : [
                        {
                            "Sid" : "IPAllow",
                            "Effect" : "Allow",
                            "Principal" : {
                                "AWS" : "*"
                            },
                            "Action" : [
                                "s3:ListBucket",
                                "s3:GetObject"
                            ],
                            "Resource" : [
                                { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "arn:aws:s3:::", { "Ref" : "PrivateBucket" } ] ] },
                                { "Fn::Join" : [ "", [ "arn:aws:s3:::", { "Ref" : "PrivateBucket" }, "/*" ] ] }
                            ],
                            "Condition" : {
                                "IpAddress" : {
                                    "aws:SourceIp" : [
                                        "ip/cid/r",
                                        "ip/cid/r",
                                        "ip/cid/r",
                                        "ip/cid/r",
                                        "ip/cid/r"                                        
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                },
                "Bucket" : { "Ref" : "PrivateBucket" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you create a user, attach Lambda's policy and see if the user can access your bucket?

Comment: @helloV not sure how to do that? from what i've seen, all our cf scripts have the policy stuff in the script itself

Comment: you need to add permissions for ListBucket operation too. can you try with that?

Comment: @ketan ill try that; but isnt "headObject" covered by "getObject"?

Comment: i am talking about list-bucket, not get-object. these two are different things.

Comment: @ketan added listobject but still fails; i dont think it needed listobject since with getobject i was able to get metadata for a file that exist but for file that doesnt exist i get a "forbidden" error

Comment: i meant listbucket...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

see doc http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectHEAD.html

> If you have the s3:ListBucket permission on the bucket, Amazon S3 will return a HTTP status code 404 ("no such key") error.
>
> If you don’t have the s3:ListBucket permission, Amazon S3 will return a HTTP status code 403 ("access denied") error.

my code was trying to run headobject on a nonexistent item; so the error that i got was "forbidden" which was correct, since i didnt have the listbucket permission for neither the s3 bucket nor the lambda...